# App somewhat rejected by Apple - They need more info about payment

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

The app we're working on in my company has been "almost rejected" this morning because Apple needs more information about the aquiring of user accounts and payment for the service our app provides. Here's the words from Apple (adapted, as I cannot include the app name):

1. How does the user acquire login credentials to APPNAME?
2. Is the service free?
3. If accounts are free is there an option to upgrade to a paid account in anyway?

That's the questions, now here's a description of what our app does:

We have an online service based on a website that allow users to upload pictures and a description from a pc, mac or any smartphone platform. This service requires a user account, which one buys from us. After that, the user can access the website, upload pictures to it etc. 
But they're also able to login with their smartphones (android, iOS and WP7), making it possible to upload photos from the phones camera to the website.

What I'm trying to say is that the app it self is NOT the main product, the website is, and that's what the users pay for. The app is just an accessory that we've made available for free for the existing users.

But how do we write this to Apple in a way that they won't misunderstand, and reject the app because it must have IAP or something?

Hoping someone out there has some nice tips!

Comment: How did this turn out? We're in the same situation...

Comment: We explained how our service worked and they accepted it :) 
Our app is a part of a bigger system, so the app itself is not our product, but only an extra service so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to restrict the user from paying for anything via the app. Have a look at the following guidelines Apple impose:

> 1. Purchasing and currencies
>
>    11.1
>
>    Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality
>      with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>      11.2
>
>    Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP)
>      to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be
>      rejected
>      11.3
>
>    Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services
>      used outside of the application will be rejected
>      11.4
>
>    Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must
>      consume those credits within the application
>      11.5
>
>    Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies that
>      expire will be rejected

It's probable that you may have to remove the feature that allows users to sign up via the mobile devices (or at least the feature that asks them to pay) and use the app as 'just an accessory'.

Comment: We do not ask the users to pay for anything in the app, as it is "just an accessory".

Comment: Then I expect that's what you have to explain to Apple. Clarify that there is no money exchanged via the app though a user can upgrade via your website. I'm not sure Apple will allow this anyway, but if they do, they may be awkward about allowing you to advertise that users must go to your site

Comment: We're in the middle of creating a long and thorough answer for Apple, explaining that it's just an accessory app. We know of other companies that does this kind of thing(example: perforce.com). So it should be possible to get it through.

Comment: Did Apple accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problems with your application is that you are proving some username and password in your application. Now consider following case.

1. Someone downloads you application but do not have any account in your website.
   -> Will he be able to make a new account from iPhone Application?
   if answer is no then he has to go to your website to make a new account. and maybe there you will be asking for some payment. Thus it is not fitting apples policies because you may sell application from appstore and collect payment from somewhere else. So provide provision to make a new user account in you application.
2. Do your website allows to upload any number of photons free?
   -> If answer to above is no then you must provide provision for making payment in you application also.

Apple's main problem is that your application has some possible way to access content(like Storage space in your case) which was sold outside apple store.

So find some workaround for that......

Good Luck